# Как получить данные сервлету от ajax-запроса?

Tags: java, ajax, servlet

С помощью такого запроса

```
    $('#add_author').submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/addauthor",
                    data: $("#author_name").val(),
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#content").html(html);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Обращаюсь к такому сервлету

```
    public class AddAuthorServlet extends HttpServlet {
        public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

            response.setContentType("text/html");

            String authorName = request.toString();
          //String authorName = request.getParameter("genre-name");

            SocketConnection.output.println("add_genre " + authorName);
          //String string = SocketConnection.input.readLine();
            RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("workshop.html");
            rs.forward(request, response);
       }
   }
```

Пытаюсь передать значение `author_name`, сервлет не получает ничего. Как правильно передать с помощью `ajax`-запроса это значение `servlet`'у и правильно получить его?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

где в вашем запросе обращение к данному методу?

Сервер ищет функцию "addauthor"

Comment: То есть? Запрос обращается к url `/addauthor`, а это по маппингу есть данный сервлет. Или я Вас не так понял?

Comment: Логично предположить что структура обращения к сервлету такая: AddAuthor/service

Comment: Не помогает, потому что  в web.xml прописан сервлет, он его не увидит, его обратиться как к `AddAuthor/service` <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddAuthor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>AddAuthorServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddAuthor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addauthor</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Хорошо, а он вызывает вообще эту функцию? Попробуйте поставить breakpoit вначале функции